# Null Local Variable in Overridden OnReceive

Tags: java, android, interface

I initialize the interface SMSListener in my MainActivity's onCreate but it is null in my overridden onReceive function. Am I incorrectly using the public interface variable in my onReceive? I have properly initialized the variable whenever I have tested it outside of the overridden function.

SmsReceiver:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public interface OnCustomReceiveSMS {
        void OnReceiveSMS(String inNumber, String inText);
    }
    public OnCustomReceiveSMS SMSListener;

    //constructor
    public SmsReceiver(){
        this.SMSListener = null;
    }

    //register sms listener
    public void SetCustomEventListener(OnCustomReceiveSMS eventListener){
        this.SMSListener = eventListener;
        this.SMSListener.OnReceiveSMS("test1", "test2");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         //THIS IS ALWAYS FALSE EVEN AFTER INITIALIZED
         if(this.SMSListener != null){
            Toast.makeText(context, "SMSListener is NOT null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            this.SMSListener.OnReceiveSMS("test3", "test4");
         }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "SMSListener is NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SmsReceiver smsReceiverObj;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initialize SMS receiver and register event listener
        this.smsReceiverObj = new SmsReceiver();
        this.smsReceiverObj.SetCustomEventListener(new SmsReceiver.OnCustomReceiveSMS() {
            @Override
            public void OnReceiveSMS(String inNumber, String inText) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test event listener fired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
   }
}
```

The first test in SetCustomEventListener (test1, test2) works just fine immediately after initializing the interface variable. When I try using it in onReceive function later I always get the "SMSListener is NULL" debug message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be a sticky `broadcast`, which will call `onReceive` method before you even `setCustomEventListener`, better way to do it is to initialize it in constructor

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public interface OnCustomReceiveSMS {
        void OnReceiveSMS(String inNumber, String inText);
    }
    public OnCustomReceiveSMS SMSListener;

    //constructor
    public SmsReceiver(OnCustomReceiveSMS eventListener){
        this.SMSListener = eventListener;
        this.SMSListener.OnReceiveSMS("test1", "test2");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         //THIS IS ALWAYS FALSE EVEN AFTER INITIALIZED
         if(this.SMSListener != null){
            Toast.makeText(context, "SMSListener is NOT null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            this.SMSListener.OnReceiveSMS("test3", "test4");
         }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "SMSListener is NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    }
}
```

And in your activity

```
this.smsReceiverObj = new SmsReceiver(new SmsReceiver.OnCustomReceiveSMS() {
            @Override
            public void OnReceiveSMS(String inNumber, String inText) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test event listener fired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

**EDIT**

Problem is you are trying to register it in `Manifest`, remove `receiver` from manifest and register it inside the `MainActivity` , It will work like a charm

```
this.smsReceiverObj = new SmsReceiver(new SmsReceiver.OnCustomReceiveSMS() {
                @Override
                public void OnReceiveSMS(String inNumber, String inText) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test event listener fired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
registerReceiver(this.smsReceiverObj,new IntentFilter());
```

Comment: I have ensured that setCustomEventListener() is called before onReceive with debug messages. The SmsReceiver object does seem to have a valid SMSListener variable but it's like onReceive can't access it. I should have mentioned I did try passing it in the constructor as well.

Comment: try using above receiver and print your logs , so we can know why it's happening

Comment: After testing again passing through the constructor, test1/2 still passes, but when I receive a text and onReceive fires the app now crashes.

Comment: Seems something unrelated. I need to make an empty constructor.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.aptbyte.apps.autoresponse.SmsReceiver: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.aptbyte.apps.autoresponse.SmsReceiver> has no zero argument constructor

Comment: In the manifest here: <receiver android:name="com.aptbyte.apps.autoresponse.SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true">

Comment: Close but registerReceiver() won't take my smsReceiverObj. Do I need to cast or add another parameter?

Comment: Updated the answer, you need to add `IntentFilter`

Comment: Ah hah! I needed to add a filter. You nailed it! 
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.setPriority(1000);
        filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        registerReceiver(this.smsReceiverObj, filter);

Comment: Glad I could help, Happy coding :)